# Example for a differentiable function with the following property

Tags: calculus, functions

Give an example for a differentiable function, which has an extrema at 0, but it's derivative does not change it's sign.

I think, that the function $sin(1/x)$ can be maybe a good solution, becaise at the point 0, it has infinity "many waves"

Comment: ... constant zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, for a non-constant example, $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \exp(-1/x), \,\,x > 0 \\ 0, \,\, x\leqslant 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Could you maybe explain me briefly why is it a good example? I appreciate your answer

Comment: Its just the first thing that came to mind besides a constant.  There is a minimum at $x=0$ although not strict.

Comment: You may want to be more specific in the question about the domain of the required function.  There are trivial examples like $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x) = x$.

Comment: That should suffice.  +1.  Even $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2&,x\ge 0\\\\0&x<0\end{cases}$ works.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks. That should have been obvious. Have a nice a Thanksgiving.

Comment: @RRL Thank you.  And you also!  -Mark